# Polars dataframe: add columns conditional on other column yielding different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I have the following dataframe in `polars`.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "Buy_Signal": [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
    "Returns": np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 5),
})
```

Ultimately, I want to do aggregations on column `Returns` conditional on different intervals - which are given by column `Buy_Signal`. In the above case the length is from each `1` to the end of the dataframe.

**What is the most polar way to do this?**

My "stupid" solution (before I can apply aggregations) is as follows:

```
df = (df
      .with_columns(pl.col("Buy_Signal").cum_sum().alias("Holdings"))

      # (1) Determine returns for each holding period (>=1, >=2) and melt into one column
      .with_columns([
            pl.when(pl.col("Holdings") >= 1).then(pl.col("Returns")).alias("Port_1"),
            pl.when(pl.col("Holdings") >= 2).then(pl.col("Returns")).alias("Port_2"),
            ])
      )
```

The solution is obviously not working for many "buy signals". So I wrote a separate function `calc_port_returns` which includes a for loop which is then passed to polar's `pipe` function. See here:

```
def calc_port_returns(_df: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    n_portfolios = _df["Buy_Signal"].sum()
    data = pl.DataFrame()
    _df = _df.with_columns(pl.col("Buy_Signal").cum_sum().alias("Holdings"))
    for i in range(1, n_portfolios + 1):
        tmp = (
                _df.with_columns(
                pl.when(pl.col("Holdings") >= i).then(pl.col("Returns")).alias(f"Port_{i}"),
                )
                .select(pl.col(f"Port_{i}"))
                )
        data = pl.concat([data, tmp], how="horizontal")
    _df = pl.concat([_df, data], how="horizontal")
    return _df

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "Buy_Signal": [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
    "Returns": np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 5),
})

df.pipe(calc_port_returns)
```

What is the "polars" way to do this? In pandas I could imagine solving it using `df.assign({f"Port_{i}": ... for i in range(1, ...)})` with a few prior extra columns / side calculations.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty similar to what you were thinking...

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        Holdings = pl.col('Buy_Signal').cum_sum()
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("Holdings")>=x)
        .then(pl.col("Returns")).alias(f"Port_{x}")
        for x in range(1,df['Buy_Signal'].sum()+1)
        )
)
shape: (5, 5)
┌────────────┬───────────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ Buy_Signal ┆ Returns   ┆ Holdings ┆ Port_1    ┆ Port_2    │
│ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64        ┆ f64       ┆ i64      ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞════════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1          ┆ -0.05515  ┆ 1        ┆ -0.05515  ┆ null      │
│ 0          ┆ 0.205705  ┆ 1        ┆ 0.205705  ┆ null      │
│ 1          ┆ -0.068856 ┆ 2        ┆ -0.068856 ┆ -0.068856 │
│ 0          ┆ -0.141231 ┆ 2        ┆ -0.141231 ┆ -0.141231 │
│ 0          ┆ -0.028524 ┆ 2        ┆ -0.028524 ┆ -0.028524 │
└────────────┴───────────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a dedicated Polars method for this type of *"overlapping groups"* problem.

i.e. something where you could use expressions to specify the start/end(s)

```py
.some_special_group_by(
   start = pl.col("Buy_Signal") == 1, 
   end = pl.int_range(pl.len()) == pl.len() - 1
)
```

You can get the range of indices:

```py
idxs = df.select(index = 
    pl.when(pl.col("Buy_Signal") == 1)
      .then(pl.int_ranges(pl.int_range(pl.len()), pl.len()))
)
```

```py
shape: (5, 1)
┌─────────────────┐
│ index           │
│ ---             │
│ list[i64]       │
╞═════════════════╡
│ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] │
│ null            │
│ [2, 3, 4]       │
│ null            │
│ null            │
└─────────────────┘
```

And use them in a `.join()`

```py
(idxs.explode("index").drop_nulls().cast(pl.UInt32)
    .join(df.with_row_index(), on="index", how="left")
    .with_columns(group = 
       (pl.col("index") == pl.col("index").max())
          .shift().cum_sum().backward_fill()
    )
)
```

```py
shape: (8, 4)
┌───────┬────────────┬───────────┬───────┐
│ index ┆ Buy_Signal ┆ Returns   ┆ group │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---   │
│ u32   ┆ i64        ┆ f64       ┆ u32   │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═══════════╪═══════╡
│ 0     ┆ 1          ┆ -0.05515  ┆ 0     │
│ 1     ┆ 0          ┆ 0.205705  ┆ 0     │
│ 2     ┆ 1          ┆ -0.068856 ┆ 0     │
│ 3     ┆ 0          ┆ -0.141231 ┆ 0     │
│ 4     ┆ 0          ┆ -0.028524 ┆ 0     │
│ 2     ┆ 1          ┆ -0.068856 ┆ 1     │
│ 3     ┆ 0          ┆ -0.141231 ┆ 1     │
│ 4     ┆ 0          ┆ -0.028524 ┆ 1     │
└───────┴────────────┴───────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although @MacGregor's answer is more directly related to my immediate question, this helps me to understand polars a bit better. Very helpful!