# Polars dataframe: overlapping groups

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I am currently converting code from pandas to polars as I really like the api. This question is a more generally question to a previous question of mine (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77868799/polars-dataframe-add-columns-conditional-on-other-column-yielding-different-len))

I have the following dataframe

```py
# Dummy data
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "Buy_Signal": [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
    "Returns": [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.00, -0.01],
})
```

I want to ultimately do aggregations on column `Returns` conditional on different intervals - which are given by column `Buy_Signal`. In the above case the length is from each 1 to the end of the dataframe. The resulting dataframe should therefore look like this

```
shape: (15, 2)
┌───────┬─────────┐
│ group ┆ Returns │
│ ---   ┆ ---     │
│ i64   ┆ f64     │
╞═══════╪═════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 0.01    │
│ 1     ┆ 0.02    │
│ 1     ┆ 0.03    │
│ 1     ┆ 0.02    │
│ 1     ┆ 0.01    │
│ 1     ┆ 0.0     │
│ 1     ┆ -0.01   │
│ 2     ┆ 0.03    │
│ 2     ┆ 0.02    │
│ 2     ┆ 0.01    │
│ 2     ┆ 0.0     │
│ 2     ┆ -0.01   │
│ 3     ┆ 0.01    │
│ 3     ┆ 0.0     │
│ 3     ┆ -0.01   │
└───────┴─────────┘
```

One approach posted as an answer to my previous question is the following:

```py
# Build overlapping group index
idx = df.select(index=
          pl.when(pl.col("Buy_Signal") == 1)
          .then(pl.int_ranges(pl.int_range(pl.len()), pl.len()  ))
).explode(pl.col("index")).drop_nulls().cast(pl.UInt32)

# Join index with original data
df = (df.with_row_index()
    .join(idx, on="index")
    .with_columns(group = (pl.col("index") == pl.col("index").max())
                .shift().cum_sum().backward_fill() + 1)
    .select(["group", "Returns"])
)
```

**Question:** Are there other solutions to this problem that are both readable and fast?

My actual problem contains much larger datasets. Thanks

Comment: you don't need a join at all try    df.with_columns instead of df.select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, here is an alternative solution that doesnt rely on experimental functionality.

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("Buy_Signal").cum_sum().alias("group")
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.int_ranges(pl.col("group").min(), pl.col("group")+1)
    )
    .explode("group")
    .sort("group")
)
```

**Output.**

```py
shape: (15, 3)
┌────────────┬─────────┬───────┐
│ Buy_Signal ┆ Returns ┆ group │
│ ---        ┆ ---     ┆ ---   │
│ i64        ┆ f64     ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═════════╪═══════╡
│ 1          ┆ 0.01    ┆ 1     │
│ 0          ┆ 0.02    ┆ 1     │
│ 1          ┆ 0.03    ┆ 1     │
│ 0          ┆ 0.02    ┆ 1     │
│ 1          ┆ 0.01    ┆ 1     │
│ …          ┆ …       ┆ …     │
│ 0          ┆ 0.0     ┆ 2     │
│ 0          ┆ -0.01   ┆ 2     │
│ 1          ┆ 0.01    ┆ 3     │
│ 0          ┆ 0.0     ┆ 3     │
│ 0          ┆ -0.01   ┆ 3     │
└────────────┴─────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach, you can probably even do `int_ranges(1, pl.col("group")+1)`. Based on warning on `cumulative_eval()` this one might also work faster

Comment: @RomanPekar Yes, this is indeed valid under the assumption that the `Buy_Signal` column  starts with a 1.

Comment: @Hericks Thanks for the response. Really like the solution. Easy to read and grasp (almost) at first sight.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a good case for usage of [`cumulative_eval()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.cumulative_eval.html).

From the first glance, you need to have 2 passes on your DataFrame. First, you need to calculate [`cum_sum`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.cum_sum.html#polars.cum_sum) to get the grouping right:

```
df = df.with_columns(
        Holdings = pl.col('Buy_Signal').cum_sum()
    ).group_by("Holdings").agg(
        pl.col(["Returns"])).sort("Holdings", descending=True
    )

print(df)

shape: (3, 2)
┌──────────┬────────────────────┐
│ Holdings ┆ Returns            │
│ ---      ┆ ---                │
│ i64      ┆ list[f64]          │
╞══════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 3        ┆ [0.01, 0.0, -0.01] │
│ 2        ┆ [0.03, 0.02]       │
│ 1        ┆ [0.01, 0.02]       │
└──────────┴────────────────────┘
```

Note that currently our DataFrame is sorted with `descending=True`, that's important, cause we want our lists to be aggregated from largest group to smallest.

And now [`cumulative_eval()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.cumulative_eval.html), together with [`implode()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.implode.html):

```
df = df.with_columns(
        pl.col("Returns").cumulative_eval(pl.element().explode().implode())
    )

print(df.explode("Returns"))

shape: (15, 2)
┌──────────┬─────────┐
│ Holdings ┆ Returns │
│ ---      ┆ ---     │
│ i64      ┆ f64     │
╞══════════╪═════════╡
│ 3        ┆ 0.01    │
│ 3        ┆ 0.0     │
│ 3        ┆ -0.01   │
│ 2        ┆ 0.01    │
│ …        ┆ …       │
│ 1        ┆ 0.03    │
│ 1        ┆ 0.02    │
│ 1        ┆ 0.01    │
│ 1        ┆ 0.02    │
└──────────┴─────────┘
```

You can see that result match with what you would expect. However, you have to be careful about performance, as there's a note in `cumulative_eval` documentation:

> Warrning
>
> This functionality is experimental and may change without it being
> considered a breaking change.
>
> This can be really slow as it can have O(n^2) complexity. Don’t use
> this for operations that visit all elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have not used `cumulative_eval` and will dig into this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some more info as I think the question title is based on my previous poor wording:

I found an existing definition of the problem (which may be a better title for the question?)

A Polars equivalent to SQL's `ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` [window framing.](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/window_functions.html#row-framing)

```py
┌────────────┬─────────┐
│ Buy_Signal ┆ Returns │
│ ---        ┆ ---     │
│ i64        ┆ f64     │ # New "group/window" starts when Buy_Signal == 1
╞════════════╪═════════╡ # 
│ 1          ┆ 0.01    │ # ┌─ group 1 ─┐
│ 0          ┆ 0.02    │ # │           │ 
│ 1          ┆ 0.03    │ # │           │┌─ group 2 ─┐
│ 0          ┆ 0.02    │ # │           ││           │ 
│ 1          ┆ 0.01    │ # │           ││           │┌─ group 3 ─┐
│ 0          ┆ 0.0     │ # │           ││           ││           │
│ 0          ┆ -0.01   │ # └───────────┘└───────────┘└───────────┘
└────────────┴─────────┘
```

e.g. using [DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview.html) to demonstrate:

```py
duckdb.sql("""
from df
select 
   buy_signal, 
   returns, 
   case when buy_signal = 1
   then
      list(returns) over (rows between current row and unbounded following)
   end as group
""")
```

```py
┌────────────┬─────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Buy_Signal │ Returns │                   group                    │
│   int64    │ double  │                  double[]                  │
├────────────┼─────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│          1 │    0.01 │ [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.0, -0.01] │
│          0 │    0.02 │ NULL                                       │
│          1 │    0.03 │ [0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.0, -0.01]             │
│          0 │    0.02 │ NULL                                       │
│          1 │    0.01 │ [0.01, 0.0, -0.01]                         │
│          0 │     0.0 │ NULL                                       │
│          0 │   -0.01 │ NULL                                       │
└────────────┴─────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I used your wording! The most difficult part of asking such questions is to concisely formulate the problem. Helpful to see that there is some kind of pattern for this.

Comment: @FredMaster I think it may also depend on the specific aggregations being performed. e.g. if it was just "cum_sum" - you could perform it on the whole dataframe, then at each `Buy_Signal == 1` use subtraction to get the "value" from that point onwards.